# how to do string.contains in dart like find_in_set in mysql?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a String1 : "baby,fetus,"
and String2 : "baby fetus"

I want to check if inputString1 == "baby" 
using String1.contain(inputString1) 
will return TRUE

BUT I also want to check if 
using string2.contain(inputString1)
will return FALSE

Beacause if there are choices (separated by comma), they are true,
but if THERE ARE NO comma, I want the the string to be EXACTLY same,

or if String3 "baby fetus, baby boy,", 
-> if input "baby fetus" = true,
-> if input "baby" = false.

How to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this code is working for me right now :

```
stringX = "baby fetus"
stringX.toString().split(",").contains("baby") //false
stringX.toString().split(",").contains("baby fetus") //true

stringX = "baby,fetus"
stringX.toString().split(",").contains("baby") //true
stringX.toString().split(",").contains("baby fetus") //false
```